# how to customize notification of control-m?

Tags: notifications, control-m

I want to send a http request to my own applications  when job ended ok ?
Is this notification supported by control-m Or Is there any other ways to fulfill my requests?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYzgq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is best achieved via the "shout destination" table. Create a shout destination that is of the 'P' type (i.e. program). Point the destination to a simple script that sends a curl instruction to your desired http address.

If you want avoid shout destinations, try using the post-command field in the jobdef but it conditional on the main job working.

Comment: What if the server (i.e. windows 10) where control-m is installed does not have curl command installed ?  what's worse is that I can't install anything on that server.

Comment: Well the is the Control-M Web Messaging module, but you need to install that on the Control-M Agent, so that is no help. I would use a shout destination where you run a program on the Control-M Server, you should be able to invoke curl from there.